# get the location without using internet in android and with using network provide?

Tags: android, networking, location, provider

How to  get the location without using internet in android. How to use the network provider to get the location. Is the internet necessary for network provider. How does the network provider work and how to use that in android?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question is too vague and it is clear that you didn't even try researching first. https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

Comment: sorry for inconvenience..i searched..but i didn't get a clear vision about that...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FusedLocationProvider`, and it all comes down to the `LocationRequest` [priority](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setPriority(int)) you set.